# How to only run JS file with the code runner extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm wanting to start to use JS in VS Code, so I installed the code runner extension to help me out. But I have a problem when I run a python it wanted to go through the code runner extension and not that python extension that I already have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First install node js to run code through code runner extension or you can simply run the js file by the following way:

**node filename.js**

example:
**node index.js**

**Remember:** you need to first install node js globally and check whether it is installed perfectly or not, by checking version through *node --version* command in cmd.